# Alternative for injecting a IUnityContainer dependency when using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

So in asp.net 4 I had this class

```
 public class Dispatcher : IDispatcher
    {
        private IUnityContainer container;

        public Dispatcher(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }

        public async Task Dispatch<T>(T evt) where T : IAtomicEvent
        {
            try
            {
                var d1 = typeof(IHandlesAtomically<>);
                Type[] typeArgs = { evt.GetType() };
                var makeme = d1.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

                var handler = container.Resolve(makeme);
                await ((Task)handler.GetType()
                      .GetMethod("HandleAsync")
                      .Invoke(handler, new object[] { evt }));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }


            return;
        }
```

and in UnityConfig I had

```
container.RegisterType<IDispatcher, Dispatcher>();
container.RegisterType<IHandlesAtomically<PromotionCreated>, PromotionCreatedHandler>();
```

In asp.net core Startup.cs I have added

```
services.AddSingleton<IDispatcher, Dispatcher>();
services.AddSingleton<IHandlesAtomically<PromotionCreated>, PromotionCreatedHandler>();
```

The error I am getting is

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Unity.IUnityContainer' while attempting to activate
>   'RatesAvailability.Infrastructure.Dispatcher.Dispatcher'.

So how can I resolve makeme without using IUnityContainer?

Comment: Is the intention to use unity with core?

Comment: @Nkosi i dont understand your question. i am trying to rewrite code from asp.net 4 to asp.net core

Comment: I believe unity has extensions for core so I wanted to clarify if the intention was to continue using unity via the extension point or if you wanted the built-in DI.

Comment: @Nkosi I have no need for using unity in core

Comment: Ok then in that case replace the container with `IServiceProvider` and use that to resolve services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the container with `IServiceProvider` and use that to resolve services

```
public class Dispatcher : IDispatcher {
    private readonly IServiceProvider provider;

    public Dispatcher(IServiceProvider provider) {
        this.provider = provider
    }

    public Task Dispatch<T>(T evt) where T : IAtomicEvent {
        try {
            var d1 = typeof(IHandlesAtomically<>);
            Type[] typeArgs = { evt.GetType() };
            var makeme = d1.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

            var handler = provider.GetService(makeme);
            return ((Task)handler.GetType()
                  .GetMethod("HandleAsync")
                  .Invoke(handler, new object[] { evt }));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

If there are issues injecting the provider by default then consider using the factory delegate when configuring services

```
services.AddSingleton<IDispatcher>(serviceProvider => new Dispatcher(serviceProvider));
```

Comment: Yes, already got it. Works fine. Before posting this question i tried using IServiceCollection to create serviceProvider using BuildServiceProvider, but that obviously didnt work.

Comment: Be careful not to register  the `Dispatcher` as singleton in MS.DI. Doing so would inject the `Dispatcher` with the root service provider. Resolving your `IHandlesAtomically<>` implementations from the root container, making them and all their dependencies effectively singletons. This could lead to memory leaks, race conditions, and other hard to track bugs. Best is to register *anything* that gets injected with `IServiceProvider` using `AddScoped`.

Comment: Adding the dispatcher using `AddSingleton`, however, would work if the `Dispatch` method creates a new `IServiceScope` and resolves the handlers from that scope (and disposes the scope at the end of the method.